# Is it valid for a hostname to start with a digit?

Tags: hostname

Is it valid for a hostname to start with a digit? e.g. `8server`

From reading [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13) it would appear that this is a valid hostname. However, I'm not clear on whether a hostname can only start with a digit when there is a suffix e.g. `8server.com`

The origin of this question is that `InternetDomainName.isValid("8server");` in the Google Guava library ([Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html)) rejects the input. I also posted a specific question on the [Guava Discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/8Sycya7Fkok) group.

Comment: I was going to say 'no', but that RFC clearly says it's ok. I don't think it matters regarding domain name. However I'd still be wary of doing it, because it _used_ to be invalid, and a lot of people may still be under the same misconception as I was :)

Comment: An interesting question, +1 from me, but I note that the example you quote above is a domain name, not a hostname (which would be, eg, `8server.example.com`).  Could you clarify what the question's about, as the answers may differ?

Comment: @MadHatter I've edited the question to clarify why I have asked this.

Comment: Thank you!  I only wish I were enough of a programmer to know what that call does, so I could answer the question myself!

Comment: Concerning the call to isValid(), did you try `InternetDomainName.isValid("8server.com");`, as isValid() is expecting a domain name?

Comment: As a kind of proof by example, they do exist: http://www.7dayshop.com/

Comment: How about a digit-only hostname? http://www.88888888.cn/

Comment: @CélineAussourd 8server.com is accepted as a valid domain name. The Guava code specifically checks for a name with a single part starting with a number to reject it. I have posted a question on their Google Group as well. However, I also wanted to ask here to get a general answer for reference.

Comment: `4chan.com` is a valid (and well known) host name that starts with a number.

Comment: I'm aware of .com addresses etc starting with a digit. As I mentioned in my question it wasn't clear whether a hostname without a . and starting with a digit was valid e.g. "8server"

Comment: @Mark You seem to think that there's a rule stating that a tld name must not start with a digit. That's not true and that's exactly what RFC 1123 deprecates. It should even be technically possible to use fully numeric TLDs in DNS with some restrictions (e.g. forbid 4 digits TLD names as it will be resolved as an IP address by most implementations and resolved as such, bypassing DNS query) in the future. For instance I remember the [42 registry project](https://twitter.com/42registry) that served the TLD `.42`.

Comment: @XavierLucas I think the problem is that the rules are spread over any number of RFCs and aren't completely clear. But I agree with your point. On the Guava Discuss thread it was pointed out that in a `.111` TLD `222.222.222.111` would be an IPv4 address while `999.999.999.111` would be a hostname!

Comment: How can you forget [9gag.com](http://9gag.com/)? :D

Comment: @IQAndreas, 4chan.org is a good enough reason to make it *invalid*. (Just kidding anonymous, don't hurt me.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[RFC 1123](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1123) relaxes a constraint of RFC 952 which specifies a legacy of the *Hostname Server Protocol* (described in [RFC 953](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc953)) replaced by DNS.
So a fully numeric hostname would be valid per these RFCs.

RFC 1123 itself discusses consequences when it comes to IP versus hostname parsing :

> If a dotted-decimal number can be entered without such
> identifying delimiters, then a full syntactic check must be
> made, because a segment of **a host domain name is now allowed
> to begin with a digit and could legally be entirely numeric**
> (see Section 6.1.2.4).  However, a valid host name can never
> have the dotted-decimal form #.#.#.#, since at least the
> highest-level component label will be alphabetic.

However, it was provided in [RFC 1178](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1178) guidelines to choose a valid hostname because of implementations issues. A lot of these implementations don't recognize numeric hostnames well and try to parse them as if they were IPs until they contain at least one non-numeric character no matter the location.

Also, you will find that implementations don't always honor other original constraints of RFC 952, allowing for instance the hostname to end with a minus sign or a period.

DNS preserved these original specifications for hostnames and added support for underscores ([RFC 2782](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt)).

**Update** As requested in comments, clarification for the sentence : *However, a valid host name can never have the dotted-decimal form #.#.#.#, since at least the highest-level component label will be alphabetic*. This means the top level domain name must be *alphabetic*, thus the fully qualified hostname can never be confused with an IPv4 address. This idea has been clarified by [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-2) for DNS and changed to *not all-numeric*. Note the slight difference.

Comment: Keep in mind that implementations which couldn't handle digits in names dated back to the 1980s; RFC 1178 was published in 1990. Anything that can't handle it _now_ is simply buggy.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You would be surprised of how many implementations *still* don't honor these RFCs. Starting from your linux hosts file handling.

Comment: Haha, no I wouldn't. Hardly a day goes by that I _don't_ have cause to beat some developer over the head with an RFC.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: You wouldn't believe the shit I see from devs at times. Couple of weeks ago I had one who had made a network-config webpage in a ip-camera so that the user could enter the hostname for the camera. He didn't do ANY validation on the free-format user-input. Beta-test user entered "Room 1.10" and the camera happily send that as DHCP client identifier. I can assure you Microsoft DHCP and DNS servers don't like that. Good thing I noticed before that got into the production build. I can only shudder at the thought what sometimes does get through to the customer...

Answer (score 15):

Originally the hostname couldn't start with a digit or underscore ([RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952)) but the new specification RFC 1123, as you mentioned, allows it.

Concerning the call to isValid(), in this case, the full domain name should be passed in parameter: `InternetDomainName.isValid("8server.com");`

Comment: Should a full domain name really need to be passed to the isValid method? After all `InternetDomainName.isValid("server");` returns true.

Comment: @Mark OK, I updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 9):

Yes. RFC 1123 clearly allows it and here's an example:

http://9292.nl/

It's the route planner for Dutch public transportation.

Comment: There are plenty more: http://9gag.com, http://4chan.org, etc.